# siteurls.config and url rewiriting in dotnetnuke 9

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

rewriting url and human friendly url is very important in `seo` and performance. dnnurlprovider is default ur rewiter for DNN and rule is written in siteurls.config and DNN 9:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RewriterConfig>
    <Rules>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*DesktopDefault.aspx(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/Default.aspx$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*EditModule.aspx(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/Default.aspx$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*/TabId/(\d+)(.*)/Logoff.aspx</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/Admin/Security/Logoff.aspx?tabid=$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*/TabId/(\d+)(.*)/rss.aspx</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/rss.aspx?TabId=$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>[^?]*/TabId/(\d+)(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/Default.aspx?TabId=$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*BannerClickThrough.aspx(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/DesktopModules/Admin/Banners/BannerClickThrough.aspx$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
 <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*/m/(\d+)(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>~/rss.aspx?TabId=$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
        </Rules>

</RewriterConfig>
```

now i have added new rule to this for new url patterns:

```
<RewriterRule>
        <LookFor>.*/m/(\d+)(.*)</LookFor>
        <SendTo>~/Default.aspx?TabId=$1</SendTo>
    </RewriterRule>
```

app pool is restarted and no error is written in log folder but rewritting rule that i have added not working .
`http://domain.com/m/123 --> http://domain.com/Default.aspx?TabId=123`

this method also has been tested :

1. Installed the urlrewrite extension on my IIS
   (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)
2. Added the following code
   snippet to the  tag of the dnn site's web.config:
   `<rewrite><rules><rule name="UrlRewriteService" stopProcessing="true"><match url="^.*/m/(.*)$"/><action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx?TabId={R:1}" /></rule></rules></rewrite>`

Comment: What version of DNN are you on? There's all sorts of other handling going on in DNN 7.1+

Comment: @ChrisHammond dnn9

Comment: You might need to tweak the SEO/URL Management/Expressions setting: Site URLs Only Regular Expression to include that /m/ path, I'm not 100% sure

Comment: i have founded third party module to do this but i want to do it manually with iis configuration or own dnn . any further information exist to do in dnn9 ?